# How to change the style color of svg via css

Tags: html, css, svg

I am currently building my first website and wanted to implement some svg's. I downloaded some and changed them up a bit with inkscape. The color for the svg is saved like this:

```
<path
     d="M 44.00,166.00 ..."
     style="fill:#000000;" />
```

is there a way to change the color with css. For example if i hover over it it changes the color?

Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: add a class to your path and put the style into the css declaration. keep in mind that a style defined online overrides any concurring definitions in the class. also note that for svg elements, the css property is called `fill` as opposed to `background` for other DOM elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have it surrounded with `<svg>` so it would be something like:

```
<svg class='icon' [...]>
   <path d="M 44.00,166.00 ..."
     style="fill:#000000;" />
</svg>
```

Then you can change it with:

```
.icon path {
  fill: red;
}
```

Notice that it's not the SVG that gets `fill` but *path* inside the SVG element.